# Error Image Upload and Get, Method App\Image::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\JsonEncodingException

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, filesystems

I am uploading user profile image which is uploading and moved to storage/app/upload/images folder but when I am trying to display that image, below given error occurs.

`Method App\Image::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\JsonEncodingException`

Here is my controller function for displaying

```
public function userProfile() {   
     $image = Image::all();
    return view('frontend.layouts.Profile',compact('image'));
}
```

My view in which I am displaying image

```
@foreach($image as $images)
          <img style="width:210px ; height: 230px " src="/storage/app/upload/images/{{$images->image}}" >
```

@endforeach

Comment: Pls show the column type for `image` in your database.

Comment: column type in data base is string. $table->string('image');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Upload your image in Public directory and then try to access that, it will work fine

Comment: What If I want to upload the pictures in storage folder?

Comment: You can't, the browser only can access your public folder files like, css files, js files and all images. You should have to put these files in public folder [webroot].

Comment: for reference visit this -> [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/storage-v-public-folder)

Comment: I want to protect my uploaded images from non logged in users. So I need to put uploaded images in storage folder

Comment: You can protect these public images folder via .htaccess file 
here's the [article](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9157/29/how-to-set-up-internal-protection-for-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of making an image available to a user:

**1. As a public asset**
Here the image is made available to everyone. For instance your website logo, or landing page image would be accessed by all.  So there is a url to the image that is easily accessed by all.  These sort of files would go straight to `public/img/` folder.

**2. As a protected image available only if specific url** is requested
Here user specific images would be accessed by specific people.  Think of your members' personal photos that you want to make available only to the member herself or to some specific person.  In this case you would store the images in `storage/app/public` and make a symlink using the artisan command `php artisan storage:link` You can read more on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#configuration). Assuming that you store your files using random names using [str_random()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-str-random) you would then generate urls to your image using the asset() helper like: `echo asset('storage/X3jf5j5b2j3n.jpg');` Given that the file names are random, it would be hard to access this image by everyone excepting those who have the url generated using the asset() helper.

**3. As a protected image made available using Intervention library**
In this case you would first check if user is logged in and then dynamically load the image using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/use/http) via another protected route.  So in your web routes you would first have the user authorization using auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('user', 'UserController@userProfile');
    Route::get('images/{image}', 'UserController@serveImage'); // this route serves the image only if user is logged in
});
```

Then once your have installed Intervention library using composer, our UserController would look like:

```
use Intervention;

class UserController extends Controller
{ 
    public function userProfile()
    { 
        $images = Image::all();
        return view('frontend.layouts.Profile', compact('images'));
    }

    public function serveImage($image)
    {  
        $filename = storage_path('app/images/'.$image);
        return Intervention::make($filename)->response();
    }
}
```

You can see that the image is now being served from the `storage` folder and not `public` folder.  So this method serveImage() is called only when the route defined earlier for it is authorized.  Intervention then works its magic to read the image and send it as a http response.

Your view would change one tad bit to accommodate the new route end point that we defined called `images`.  I assume here that you are storing the filename of the image in db by a field named `filename`:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
    <img style="width:210px ; height: 230px " src="{{ url('/images/'.$image->filename) }}" >
@endforeach
```

**Note:** Do bear in mind that the preferred way to serve images is by using method 2 since it is much faster.  You can use method 3 sparingly if you really don't want anyone to even stumble upon the files using the urls.